# Why does typing quickly spike memory usage?

Tags: ios, memory

Playing around with Instruments, I noticed that while typing very quickly into a UITextView, my app's memory usage jumps up significantly, from around 30mb to 175mb. When I stop typing, it settles down again. This results in plenty of memory warnings so I was wondering, what causes it?

Comment: This is very, very unusual :| It should not happen. Did you make the tests on the simulator or the device?

Comment: It's on the device, the new iPad specifically.

Comment: One of many possible explanations is the combination of input not being immediately processed (being postponed with a pool / buffer), and the processing of input (from the pool) causing other stuff to postpone their own actions in their own pools. Basically, an yet simpler way to say it is that it's stress on the processor causing things to be saved on memory until the processor can, well, process them. It is VERY unlikely tough.

Comment: If you make a very simple app, a simple view with an UITextView, do you still experience these memory spikes?

Comment: That's basically all this is at the moment, a few other views but nothing does anything.

Comment: Just tested it in my app. Could not reproduce the issue. Try creating another test application with a textView and try to repeat the issue. Aslo check you textView delegate methods, perhaps you do something memory-expensive in there, which works only when you type.